# How do I make a button have a down state instead of an over state in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, mouseover, onmousedown

I've just put a perfectly normal default button in a WPF window, expecting it to have some normal button states. But it's only reacting to mouse over and not mouse down. I only need it to have two states so I can do without the over state. How do I get it to react to the mouse button being pressed instead?

Here is my button:

```
<Button Width="380"
        Height="80"
        FontSize="30"
        FontFamily="VAG Rounded"
        Background="#337A05"
        Foreground="White"
        Margin="0,15"
        Content="BACK TO GAMES" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right-click on the `Button` in design mode in Visual Studio and choose Edit Template->Edit a Copy and then modify the default control template as per your requirements by for example remove the `IsMouseOver` trigger and change the value of the `Background` property setter in the `IsPressed` trigger:

```
<Window...>
<Window.Resources>
<Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#FFDDDDDD"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFBEE6FD"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF3C7FB1"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="Red"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF2C628B"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFADB2B5"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383"/>
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <!--<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                            </Trigger>-->
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}"/>
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Width="380"
    Height="80"
    FontSize="30"
    FontFamily="VAG Rounded"
    Background="#337A05"
    Foreground="White"
    Margin="0,15"
    Content="BACK TO GAMES"
    Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

And no, there is no property that you can simply set to do this :) You have to override the template.

Comment: Good lord. That's inconvenient. I'd think a functional button wouldn't be something a user-friendly IDE would make its users work so hard for. I was hoping a feature like this wouldn't take more XAML than the rest of my window combined.

Comment: You could put the style in a ResourceDictionary that you merge from your App.xaml. Then you will be able to reference it from all views in your application.

Comment: Please remember to accept an answer if your issue has been solved: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Is there a shorter way to do it with C# instead of XAML?

Comment: Oh now I've discovered that it had a down state all along, but the color was so similar that I couldn't tell the difference.

Comment: No, there is no "shorter" way of doing this than to override the template.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change it's [style / template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328(v=vs.110).aspx). You'll need to get acquainted with `ControlTemplates` and `VisualStates`. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/736ca4/style-button-in-wpf/).